# Probability that a limit exists is 0

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(X_{n})_{n>0}$ be i.i.d. real valued random variables and suppose $X_{1}$ is not constant with probability 1.

Show that: P($\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n}$ exists)=0

My first idea was to let A be an arbitrary real number and to show that P($\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n}=A$)=0.In order to do so I wanted to rewrite it to a form where I could apply Borel Cantelli however I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite it to such a form. Could I get help with this question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your strategy doesn't quite work, since the limit could be a continuous random variable that doesn't take any single value with nonzero probability. You can fix this by considering intervals of possible limits instead of individual values.

Comment: And you don't need Borel-Cantelli, just use the definition of the limit. For the sequence to converge near $A$, infinitely many of the $X_n$ must fall in a small region near $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the assumption on $X_1$, we can find   a real $s$ such that $0<P(X_1 \le s)<1$. Then there must exist $t>s$ such that $P(X_1>t)>0$.
Apply Borel-Cantelli to the events $\{ X_n \le s\}$ to conclude that they occur infinitely often almost surely.
Apply Borel-Cantelli to the events $\{ X_n >t\}$ to conclude that they also occur infinitely often almost surely.

Comment: But how does one prove that the sum over P({X_n<=s}) converges? We only know something about P({X_1<=s})?

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that they all have the same distribution?

Comment: I think I got it, thanks!